# R function that can make odds ratio plot from exp(coef(glm(...)))?

Tags: r, plot

Im calculating the adjusted odds ratio with this method:

```
OR <- glm(MultipleSclerosis=="true"~Cesarean+confounder,family = binomial, data = dat)
exp(coef(OR)) ## odds ratio
exp(confint(OR)## confidence interval
```

Now I want to make an adjusted odds ratio plot showing the confidence interval. I've tried to google some functions but Im having a hard time understanding how I can make this happen. Any suggestions?

Comment: I like `plot_model` from the `sjPlot` package. You should be able to do `plot_model(OR)` and it will plot the odds ratios by default.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `plot(summary(lrm_object), log = TRUE)` after fitting a logistic model via `lrm()` function in rms package.

In your case,
`lrm_object <- lrm(MultipleSclerosis=="true" ~ Cesarean + confounder, data = dat, x = T, y = T)`